# Can emacs use window system on terminal frame? (doom-emacs, iTerm)

Tags: org-mode, frames, terminal-emacs, doom

I'm trying to set `org-level-*` height(font size) differently for each level(doom emacs, config.el):

```
(after! org   
  (set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 nil :height 1.75))
```

But it displays different height only on frame that uses window-system. I'm using OSX so ns
, in this case.

When I use frame on terminal(iTerm) it displays default height.

I think it should work with iTerm since iTerm also uses graphical display.

But the result of `(window-system)`or `(display-graphic-p)` is `nil`

Is it possible to start emacs on terminal with window system?

Comment: Many terminals use graphic displays since the 1980s e.g. MS Windows, X Windows etc. These terminals are terminal emulators - that means they emulate a old  terminal and these just do not have variables fonts. What matters is not how they look to the user but what their programming interface is and that ios basically emulation an old DEC terminal witn some extenstions

Comment: You should add that as the answer to the question. You might mention that some terminals support double–height and/or double–width characters, but that more flexible font support always happened by moving away from the traditional terminal model towards full GUIs.

Comment: Thank you. Using full GUI apps(macports, for example) is the only way to achieve partially customizing font size. It just that I can't adjust alpha(transparency) with doom emacs but iTerm can. So was trying to figure out hot to use the window system on terminal.